# What is the Spring Cloud Stream Version Compatibility for Latest Sprint Boot 2.4.1?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream

On the spring.io page for Spring Cloud Stream [link](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-stream) there's a table showing the "Release Trains":

| Spring Cloud Stream | Spring Boot | Spring Cloud |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Horsham [3.0.x] | 2.2.x | Hoxton |
| Germantown [2.2.x] | 2.1.x | Greenwich |

Does this table (current as of 12/16/2020) mean that Spring Cloud Stream does not support the latest Spring Boot 2.4.x? How else could I read this page to figure out what versions *should* be compatible?

Primarily asking due trying to upgrade from 2.3.5 (which is also not listed on the table below) to 2.4.1 and I am getting some Topic Authorization issues that were not previously happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3.1.0; the release candidate is out 3.1.0-RC1 in https://repo.spring.io/milestone

However, I have had no problems running a simple 3.0.10 app with Boot 2.4.1. Can you edit the question to show the full stack trace?

Comment: If you're seeing it run then that's all i wanted to validate. I think the issue is on my side right now so this question is solved! Thank you

Comment: I am not saying it's officially supported, just that I had no issues :)